# Get index of a meta-tag in Contact Form 7

Tags: contact-form-7

I use a meta-tag in Contact Form 7 to send email:

```
[select category "Billing" "Suggestion" "Problems"]
```

For email body I insert this shortcode:

```
Category: [category]
```

Then I get email which contains "Category: Billing", or "Category: Suggestion", or "Category: Problems".

Is it possible to use some shortcode in Contact Form 7 which returns an index number of a value in meta-tag - 1,2,3? A number instead of a word. For example, "Category: 1", or "Category: 2", "Category: 3".

Answer (score 0):

Use [pipes](https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/),

```
[select category "Billing|1" "Suggestion|2" "Problems|3"]
```